# How to send broadcast message using c# application

Tags: c#

I have some C# form application.I'm using some central data base which is developed on SQLServer2005.According to my application there are several user levels such as admin,reception,...

### problem

There is a requirement that if someone has changed the database(eg: add new record/delete record) that will be noticed admin and higher level of user.

What will be the way that should I follow to achieve this task!

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**Audit trial** could be the solution for your question. It basically means, for your data-table of concern, include the columns - 'modified_by', modified_date' in addition to 'created_by', 'created_date' columns. So whenever someone edits a record for the first time - 'modified_by' and 'modified_date' columns will be different from 'created_by' and 'created_date' columns.

And in your application, you can develop a screen (or email alert) which is accessible only for admin or higher level users, to display the modified records in reverse chronological order.

**Note**: The above audit trial method, only maintains the latest changes in database. If you want to maintain the history of edits, then you can establish the same by maintaining the audit trial information in a separate dedicated set of data-tables.

Comment: :: I agree with you but I want send some notification using pop-up box in real time.when some-one change something in the database it should be just noticed to responsible party.can I achieve that??Any way thanks for your nice reply.

Comment: Ok. You have to realize that your requirement specifies real time update which often comes with corresponding trade-off. Also you need to revisit the pop-up box approach. It may not be an optimal solution.


My humble suggestion is to go for twitter like approach. Keep a frame at the top of the screen within an ASP.net AJAX panel. Keep querying the database at regular intervals (2 mins or 5 mins) and update the panel with the latest updated information. The challenge here is to place the frame at appropriate proportions in the screen.